# Why can't I fill this 2D array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, assign

```
    Chunk** chunks[8][8];


    World () : Scene () {
        for (int xx = 0; xx < sizeof(this->chunks)-1; xx++) {
            for(int yy = 0; yy < sizeof(this->chunks[xx])-1; yy++) {

                /* Here is where I get compilation errors */
                this->chunks[xx][yy] = new Chunk(0.1f , 0.1f);
            }
        }
    }
```

"Invalid write of size 8" and "cannot convert ‘Chunk*’ to ‘Chunk**’

The Chunk constructor takes two floats (float x, float y).
How am I supposed to fill this 2 dimensional array?

(Just started to learn C++, I wrote Java before)

Comment: Dispense with the `*` symbols. Don't use `sizeof`. As a matter of style don't use `this->`. You could use a `std::vector`. It simplifies things.

Comment: Thank you!!! I thought "sizeof" returned the length of the array but I was wrong. I replaced it with sizeof(chunks)/sizeof(*chunks) and everything compiled!

Answer (score 0):

What is returned from `new Chunk(0.1f, 0.1f)`? A pointer of type `Chunk*`.

What is the type of `this->chunks[xx][yy]`? An element in your 2D array, of type `Chunk**`.

You cannot assign `Chunk*` to `Chunk**` because of type safety.

Change `Chunk** chunks[8][8];` to `Chunk* chunks[8][8];`.

Comment: That solved the conversion error, but now when I compile it I get "Core dumped". And if I run the "a.out" file using valgrind, it prints an error: "Invalid write of size 8"

Answer (score 0):

Every item in `chunks[][]` array has `Chunk**` type but `new Chunk()` operator returns pointer to Chunk (Chunk*) that's why you get cannot convert ‘Chunk*’ to ‘Chunk**’ error.

To fix this you should redeclare chunks:

```
Chunk* chunks[8][8];
```

Comment: That solved the conversion error, but now when I compile it I get "Core dumped".
And if I run the "a.out" file using valgrind, it prints an error: "Invalid write of size 8"

Comment: Post the full code that causes the problem. I also noticed that you use xx < sizeof(this->chunks)-1 condition for array intialization while it obviously should be xx < sizeof(this->chunks), may be you're faults are caused by accessing of uninitalized pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Decleration pointer doesnt accept initialization.

Chunk* chunk; is fine the you can say chunk = new int[8][8] or ...

For example, easy example of pointer usage :
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/9508/

For the convertion error, if you are using struct or class ,I can suggest *** which can be considered pointer pointest a plointer; In your case 2d array.